# MPI in Python: load data from a file by line concurrently

Tags: python, concurrency, io, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm new to python as well as MPI.
I have a huge data file, 10Gb, and I want to load it into, i.e., a list or whatever more efficient, please suggest.

Here is the way I load the file content into a list

```
def load(source, size):
     data = [[] for _ in range(size)]
          ln = 0
          with open(source, 'r') as input:
                  for line in input:
                          ln += 1
                          data[ln%size].sanitize(line)
          return data
```

Note:

- source: is file name
- size: is the number of concurrent process, I divide data into [size] of sublist.

for parallel computing using MPI in python.

Please advise how to load data more efficient and faster. I'm searching for days but I couldn't get any results matches my purpose and if there exists, please comment with a link here.

Regards

Comment: Can you provide complete working example of what you have? You talk about `mpi`, but it is not seen in your example. How much RAM do you have available? If amount of data is 10 GB, you can easily need twice as much RAM to store it in RAM. If you can, split the task to set of smaller ones. Or even better, process it in streaming manner (what assumes, your result can be produced from one line or small set of consecutive lines).

Comment: What does the file you're reading in look like, and what are you going to be doing with it?  Does every task need to look through the whole contents, or just its part?

Comment: In addition to the existing clarification questions: Are you running on a single node? What kind of file system is the file on? What kind of hardware is behind the file system? And, most importantly, what performance do you currently observe for loading the data?

Comment: @jan, the Ram is 62Gb and my concern is how I can load data concurrently  so I can reduce the loading time.

Comment: @jonathan, it is a huge csv file and yes the whole content is needed for our purposes.

Comment: @zulan, that's a multiple-node server system.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question, your bottleneck is not Python data structures. It is the I/O speed that limits the efficiency of your program.
If the file is written in continues blocks in the H.D.D then I don't know a way to read it faster than reading the file starting form the first bytes to the end.
But if the file is fragmented, create multiple threads each reading a part of the file. The must slow down the process of reading but modern HDDs implement a technique named NCQ (Native Command Queueing). It works by giving high priority to the read operation on sectors with addresses near the current position of the HDD head. Hence improving the overall speed of read operation using multiple threads.

To mention an efficient data structure in Python for your program, you need to mention what operations will you perform to the data? (delete, add, insert, search, append and so on) and how often?

By the way, if you use commodity hardware, 10GBs of RAM is expensive. Try reducing the need for this amount of RAM by loading the necessary data for computation then replacing the results with new data for the next operation. You can overlap the computation with the I/O operations to improve performance.

Comment: 16 GB commodity RAM costs less than 100 $.

Comment: @ahmad, I would like to know how I can load data concurrently so I can reduce the loading time.

Answer (score 0):

## (original) Solution using pickling

The strategy for your task can go this way:

- split the large file to smaller ones, make sure they are divided on line boundaries
- have Python code, which can convert smaller files into resulting list of records and save them as
  pickled file
- run the python code for all the smaller files in parallel (using Python or other means)
- run integrating code, taking pickled files one by one, loading the list from it and appending it
  to final result.

To gain anything, you have to be careful as overhead can overcome all possible gains from parallel
runs:

- as Python uses Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), do not use threads for parallel processing, use
  processes. As processes cannot simply pass data around, you have to pickle them and let the other
  (final integrating) part to read the result from it.
- try to minimize number of loops. For this reason it is better to:

  - do not split the large file to too many smaller parts. To use power of your cores, best fit
    the number of parts to number of cores (or possibly twice as much, but getting higher will
    spend too much time on swithing between processes).
  - pickling allows saving particular items, but better create list of items (records) and pickle
    the list as one item. Pickling one list of 1000 items will be faster than 1000 times pickling
    small items one by one.
- some tasks (spliting the file, calling the conversion task in parallel) can be often done faster
  by existing tools in the system. If you have this option, use that.

In my small test, I have created a file with 100 thousands lines with content "98-BBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
"99-BBBBBBBBBBB" etc. and tested converting it to list of numbers [...., 98, 99, ...].

For spliting I used Linux command `split`, asking to create 4 parts preserving line borders:

```
$ split -n l/4 long.txt
```

This created smaller files `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, `xad`.

To convert each smaller file I used following script, converting the content into file with
extension `.pickle` and containing pickled list.

```
# chunk2pickle.py 
import pickle
import sys


def process_line(line):
    return int(line.split("-", 1)[0])


def main(fname, pick_fname):
    with open(pick_fname, "wb") as fo:
        with open(fname) as f:
            pickle.dump([process_line(line) for line in f], fo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    pick_fname = fname + ".pickled"
    main(fname, pick_fname)
```

To convert one chunk of lines into pickled list of records:

```
$ python chunk2pickle xaa
```

and it creates the file `xaa.pickled`.

But as we need to do this in parallel, I used `parallel` tool (which has to be installed into
system):

```
$ parallel -j 4 python chunk2pickle.py {} ::: xaa xab xac xad
```

and I found new files with extension `.pickled` on the disk.

`-j 4` asks to run 4 processes in parallel, adjust it to your system or leave it out and it will
default to number of cores you have.

`parallel` can also get list of parameters (input file names in our case) by other means like `ls`
command:

```
$ ls x?? |parallel -j 4 python chunk2pickle.py {}
```

To integrate the results, use script `integrate.py`:

```
# integrate.py
import pickle


def main(file_names):
    res = []
    for fname in file_names:
        with open(fname, "rb") as f:
            res.extend(pickle.load(f))
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_names = ["xaa.pickled", "xab.pickled", "xac.pickled", "xad.pickled"]
    # here you have the list of records you asked for
    records = main(file_names)
    print records
```

In my answer I have used couple of external tools (`split` and `parallel`). You may do similar task
with Python too. My answer is focusing only on providing you an option to keep Python code for
converting lines to required data structures. Complete pure Python answer is not covered here (it
would get much longer and probably slower.

## Solution using process Pool (no explicit pickling needed)

Following solution uses multiprocessing from Python. In this case there is no need to pickle results
explicitly (I am not sure, if it is done by the library automatically, or it is not necessary and
data are passed using other means).

```
# direct_integrate.py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def process_line(line):
    return int(line.split("-", 1)[0])


def process_chunkfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return [process_line(line) for line in f]


def main(file_names, cores=4):

    p = Pool(cores)
    return p.map(process_chunkfile, file_names)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_names = ["xaa", "xab", "xac", "xad"]
    # here you have the list of records you asked for
    # warning: records are in groups.
    record_groups = main(file_names)
    for rec_group in record_groups:
        print(rec_group)
```

This updated solution still assumes, the large file is available in form of four smaller files.